# Eclipse Ctrl+Space Replace Word?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Suppose you have variables: `ID_NUMBER_50` and `ID_NUMBER_90`.
In Eclipse, when editing XML files like that of Android's; if you already have the variable `ID_NUMBER_50` and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> halfway through that word, you get the list of all possible variables with matching initial substring. Then when you select `ID_NUMBER_90`, it replaces the `50` with `90`. All Good.

However, when editing Java files, Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> at the same location would cause concatenation of the selected variable. Like - `ID_NUMBEID_NUMBER_90`. Is there any options in the settings menu or text formatting within eclipse that will also replace a word in Java like it does in XML.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I just checked and the word is replaced just like in xml files.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an IDE and not programming.

Comment: Yeah Maybe it does. But I might have played with the formatting/settings and now cannot find the option to have it so it replaces it.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, If I understand you, you want the autocomplete for JAVA.
Do this.

1. Open Eclipse.
2. In Windows, go to Window Menu, and select Preferences.
3. Select JAva Option.
4. Select Editor.
5. Select Content Editor.
6. Select "Completion overwrites"

Relevant dialog

[image]